# Bash output disappears

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, wget

When running the following bash script...

```
#!/bin/bash

ATTEMPTS=3
DEST_DIR="/opt/satnet"
ATTEMPTS=3
URL="https://github.com/google/snappy/tarball/master"

CURL_OPTS='-sIkL'
SED_REGEX='/filename=/!d;s/.*filename=(.*)$/\1/'
FILENAME="$( curl $CURL_OPTS $URL | sed -r $SED_REGEX )"
DEST_FILE="$DEST_DIR/$FILENAME"

printf "\t* URL = %s\n" $URL
printf "\t* Remote tarball filename = %s\n" $FILENAME


WGET_BIN='wget'
WGET_OPTS_1="-t $ATTEMPTS -c -O $DEST_FILE"
WGET_OPTS="-t $ATTEMPTS -c -O $DEST_FILE $URL"

printf "\t* wget opts 1 = %s\n" "$WGET_OPTS_1"
printf "\t* wget opts = %s\n" "$WGET_OPTS"

echo "    * wget opts 1 = $WGET_OPTS_1"
echo "    * wget opts = $WGET_OPTS"
```

... the output for the second variable should include the output for the first one plus the URL; however, it only displays the URL and it even does not display the part of the string that goes before the URL:

```
* URL = https://github.com/google/snappy/tarball/master
* Remote tarball filename = google-snappy-1.1.7-0-gb02bfa7.tar.gz
* wget opts 1 = -t 3 -c -O /opt/satnet/google-snappy-1.1.7-0-gb02bfa7.tar.gz
https://github.com/google/snappy/tarball/mastergle-snappy-1.1.7-0-gb02bfa7.tar.gz
* wget opts 1 = -t 3 -c -O /opt/satnet/google-snappy-1.1.7-0-gb02bfa7.tar.gz
https://github.com/google/snappy/tarball/mastersnappy-1.1.7-0-gb02bfa7.tar.gz
```

It is like if, for some reason, adding the URL "removed" the initial part of the string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely you are running into issues with curl using DOS line ends containing a *carriage return* which returns the cursor to the beginning of the line causing the first line to be overwritten by the next. (I suspect you have a carriage return captured in `$FILENAME`)

Comment: Try with the `\r` character removed from the result of `curl`: `FILENAME="$( curl $CURL_OPTS $URL | sed -r $SED_REGEX | tr -d '\r' )"`

Comment: @janos that worked it out! Please post your comment as the answer to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I was not able to reproduce the strange display error as in your question. I ran the same code in a Linux shell and it displayed just fine.
But I can confirm that the `curl` request in the posted code outputs result with DOS line endings,
which ends up in the content of the `FILENAME` variable,
which in turn may lead to strange output as you are experiencing.

An easy way to remove the offending `\r` character is to use `tr`:

```
FILENAME="$( curl $CURL_OPTS $URL | sed -r $SED_REGEX | tr -d '\r' )"
```